# Passing table data using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse [this webpage](https://fmdataba.com/19/p/1165/lionel-messi/).

As shown below, each page has the ability stats. I am eventually trying to parse all abilities into an object. `e.g. {'corners': 15, 'crossing': 15...}`

I first started to parse a single stat, `corners` by doing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
url = 'https://fmdataba.com/19/p/1165/lionel-messi/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
soup.find({"id": "fm_cro"})
```

but this returns an empty list.

Could anyone please help?

[image]

Comment: You could probably simplify your question down to simply "why can't beautiful soup find this id?" since that seems to be the real blocker. Once you've overcome that, the rest of the parsing should be up to you.

Comment: If this is the code you're using, you may want to spell check. It appears the appropriate id is 'fm_cor', not 'fm_cro'.

Comment: @ToddBurus there is an `fm_cro` id as well.

Comment: When I inspected the "Corners" row of the "Technical" column, the id I got was "fm_cor"

Comment: @ToddBurus True, however, I did a quick `document.querySelector('#fm_cro')` and got a result for the "Crossing" item.

Comment: Yes, but he's trying to get the info from the "Corners" stat row.

Comment: `soup.find(id='fm_cro').attrs` gives me an object that contains some info: `{'class': ['active'],
 'id': 'fm_cro',
 'onmouseover': "arkaa('fm_dri', '#edfd01');",
 'onmouseout': "arkaa2('fm_dri');",
 'style': 'padding-top: 10px;'}` but not the actual value of the stat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bs4 4.7.1 you can use `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` to get the different `tds` within each row to create your dict; and use `:has` and `:contains` to get the right table for each keyword and build your outer dict to house each inner.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://fmdataba.com/19/p/1165/lionel-messi/', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
abilities = ['TECHNICAL', 'MENTAL' , 'PHYSICAL']

def get_abilities(soup, keyword):
    table = soup.select_one('div:has(h3:contains("' + ability + '")) + div > table')
    d = {item.select_one('td:nth-child(odd)').text: int(item.select_one('td:nth-child(even)').text) for item in table.select('tr')}
    return d

results = {}

for ability in abilities:
    results[ability] = get_abilities(soup, ability)

print(results)
```

---

Output:

[image]

---

**CSS explanation:**

The css selector line as follows:

```
soup.select_one('div:has(h3:contains("' + ability + '")) + div > table')
```

`select_one` is like `select` in that it applies the css selector within to the soup object but only returns the first match.

`:has` and `:contains` are [pseudo classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Pseudo-classes) like `:nth-child()`. Looking at the html in question for the first ability table here is an explanation of the parts:

***Click on image to enlarge.***

[image]

---

**Additional reading:**

1. [Pseudo class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)
2. [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)
3. [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)
4. [Css selectors general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
5. [select_one](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=select_one)

Comment: so is `select_one` like a conditional selector in beautifulsoup?

Comment: It is like select but only returns the first match found. You have only two tds in each row to consider: one odd (the first), and one even, the second.

Comment: I am not familar with this syntax: `'div:has(h3:contains("' + ability + '")) ~ div > table'` Is it like an HTML condition or something?

Comment: It is a css selector. :has and :contains are pseudo class selectors supported with bs4 4.7.1 and do pretty much what they say. div:has looks for child h3 which contains your keyword. I will add some more explanation to the answer.

Comment: More explanation added. Please let me know if you are able to click on image to enlarge.

Comment: This has been really helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://fmdataba.com/19/p/1165/lionel-messi/'
page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})

tables = pd.read_html(page.text)
all_data = {}
for idx, name in [(2, 'TECHNICAL'), (3, 'MENTAL'), (4, 'PHYSICAL')]:
    tbl = tables[idx]
    data = {r[0]: r[1] for _, r in tbl.iterrows()}
    all_data[name] = data
```

`tables[2]` is the TECHNICAL table, `tables[3]` is the MENTAL table and `tables[4]` is the PHYSICAL table.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to achieve the same results without hardcoding indices to the selectors:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://fmdataba.com/19/p/1165/lionel-messi/', headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
datadict = {}
for container in ['TECHNICAL','MENTAL','PHYSICAL']:
    elem = soup.select_one(f".panel-heading:contains('{container}') + .panel-body")
    datadict[container] = {item.text:item.find_next_sibling().text for item in elem.select("td.active")}
print(datadict)
```

Output:

```
{'TECHNICAL': {'Corners': '15', 'Crossing': '15', 'Dribbling': '20', 'Finishing': '20', 'First Touch': '19', 'Free Kick': '19', 'Heading': '10', 'Long Shots': '17', 'Long Throws': '4', 'Marking': '4', 'Passing': '20', 'Penalty Taking': '17', 'Tackling': '7', 'Technique': '20'}, 'MENTAL': {'Aggression': '7', 'Anticipation': '19', 'Bravery': '10', 'Composure': '18', 'Concentration': '13', 'Decisions': '20', 'Determination': '20', 'Flair': '20', 'Leadership': '14', 'Off The Ball': '16', 'Positioning': '5', 'Teamwork': '14', 'Vision': '20', 'Work Rate': '7'}, 'PHYSICAL': {'Acceleration': '18', 'Agility': '20', 'Balance': '20', 'Jumping Reach': '6', 'Natural Fitness': '14', 'Pace': '15', 'Stamina': '13', 'Strength': '9'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kwargs), the `find()` and `find_all()` methods do not take a dictionary, they have an optional `id` keyword argument you can use.

```
soup.find(id='fm_cro')
```

This will get you the element with that id (in this case the `<td>` with "Crossing" text). If you want to get the related number you'll need to use BeautifulSoup's sibling methods to get the next adjacent `<td>` and ask it for it's text (the number).

Comment: This one gives me a `<td class="active" id="fm_cro" onmouseout="arkaa2('fm_dri');" onmouseover="arkaa('fm_dri', '#edfd01');" style="padding-top: 10px;">Crossing</td>` Not the actual value.

Comment: Right, I was giving you the solution to your code. You were searching for the id with an approach that `find()` didn't support. With that problem overcome you should be able to continue and use the documentation to get the element's text (the value).